# How to navigate between pages using Prism in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, prism

I'm trying to inject `INavigationService` into my ViewModel, so I can navigate between pages, but I don't know how to register ViewModel with parameter. Here's my App:

```
<prism:PrismApplication xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Unity;assembly=Prism.Unity.Forms"
             x:Class="PrismDemo.App" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             d1p1:Ignorable="d" xmlns:d1p1="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006">
    <prism:PrismApplication.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>

        </ResourceDictionary>
    </prism:PrismApplication.Resources>
</prism:PrismApplication>
```

and...

```
public partial class App
{
    INavigationService _navigationService;

    public App(IPlatformInitializer initializer = null) : base(initializer) { }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _navigationService = NavigationService;
        NavigationService.NavigateAsync("MainNavigationPage/Start");
    }

    protected override void RegisterTypes()
    {
        Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<MainNavigationPage>();
        Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<StartPage, StartPageViewModel>("Start");
        Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<MiddlePage, MiddlePageViewModel>("Middle");
        Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<LastPage, LastPageViewModel>("Last");
    }
}
```

How can I inject `_navigationService` into ViewModels?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually have to register the ViewModel directly as long as you have followed the convention `{MyProjectName}.Views.{MyPage}` and `{MyProjectName}.ViewModels.{MyPageViewModel}`

To use `INavigationService` in the ViewModel simply add it to the Constructor. Remember it is a named service so it must be named `navigationService`. You can check out several examples in the [Samples Repo](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Forms).

```
public class MyPageViewModel
{
    INavigationService _navigationService { get; }

    public MyPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
    {
        _navigationService = navigationService;

        NavigateCommand = new DelegateCommand<string>(OnNavigateCommandExecuted);
    }

    public DelegateCommand<string> NavigateCommand { get; }

    public async void OnNavigateCommandExecuted(string path) =>
        await _navigationService.NavigateAsync(path);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dan, but I get an exception when I add `INavigationService navigationService` parameter to the viewmodel :/

Comment: @LouisaBickley can you provide a repo of the issue?

Comment: I'm sorry, I left some code that was causing the problem. It works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `Prism`, than you should inherit your `App` from `PrismApplication`:

instead of `public partial class App` should be `public partial class App : PrismApplication`.

No need to declare `INavigationService _navigationService;` in your `App` class, because it's already declared in `PrismApplication` as `NavigationService` property.

`Prism` uses `IUnityContainer` as Dependency Injection framework, which means for you, that all, that you will register in container:

```
Container.RegisterType<ISomeService, SomeServiceImplementation>();
```

[Unity container will automatically inject in constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650802.aspx):

> Define a constructor in the target class that takes as a parameter the concrete type of the dependent class. The Unity container will instantiate and inject an instance.

`PrismApplication` registers `INavigationService` in a container, so, as I understand, you don't need to register your own instance and you could just add parameter of type `INavigationService` in constructor of view model and unity container will inject instance of registered type. The important thing, that you should give an exactly the *navigationService* name for your parameter, because `Prism` "expects" such parameter name for navigation service.

Comment: Thanks for your input. But... you said: "If you are using Prism, than you should inherit your App from PrismApplication, instead of public partial class App should be public partial class App : PrismApplication." - what's the difference?

Comment: The difference is in base class for your `App` class